# get the second element that I search in a list

Tags: python

I use python and I have a list of numbers and I would like to search a number X but I must find the second one element and if it doesn't exist I must get a msg

Example:

```
list: [5, 6, 8, 7, 9, 6, 7, 9, 2, 4, 6, 8]

X = 6

return: i = 5
```

Ps: I need the faster code because I need to repeat it in a loop of 200000 i

Comment: In question you are asking 2nd element and in return statement you have return 1st element. Please be little more clear.

Comment: He is returning the index. And it's correct because the index of the second 6 is 5

Comment: Yes exactly paolo, I search the number 6, in the list the first element has an index 1 and the second have i  = 5

Comment: I provide you an answer, let me know if it works

Comment: you can use python multiprocessing on top of the optimized code if the machine is a multiprocessor. I suggest this because all results are independent for every loop you are processing and you have 200000 iterations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A call to index searches through the list in order until it finds a match, and stops there. If you expect to need indices of more matches, you should use a list comprehension, or generator expression.

```
>>> [1, 1].index(1)
0
>>> [i for i, e in enumerate([1, 2, 1]) if e == 1]
[0, 2]
```

And then you get the second element of the result array